# Wilcoxon test for unrelated samples

Tags: r, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, bioinformatics

I have a cancer dataset with two groups of patients, those who responded to the therapy and those who did not.

I run cell type enrichment analysis, to get an idea of the cellular structure for each sample.

Now I want to know, is there significant difference between those two groups. Like for example, is there a significant difference in the `CD8+ T cells` between the two groups? If there is more among the responders, is it statisticaly significant? I need to back up my results with some numbers and p-values.

One way I thought about is wilcoxon test, using `wilcox.test()` in R, but those two groups aren't really related, besides the fact that they come from the same dataset.
Both versions of wilcoxon test assume that the pairs in the data come from dependent populations, but that is not the case here, I think. They are just random people who unfortunately happened to get cancer, other than that they are not related.

Perhaps it is why I get those warnings when I run the test?

```
There were 34 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
3: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
4: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
5: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
6: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
7: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
8: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
9: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
10: In wilcox.test.default(scores_data[i, meta_data[[column]] ==  ... :
  cannot compute exact p-value with ties
```

And here are the p-values for each cell type (38 cells overall). As you can see, although there are differences in the cells between those two groups, non of them is significant:

```
 [1] 0.40250093 0.17119738 0.89147212 0.07153246 0.88029128 0.60587761 0.47127842 0.28029665 0.33929705 0.14991494 0.13937393
[12] 0.75576986 0.36517622 0.12394517 0.91074085 0.68187885 0.34503148 0.79444772 0.36834835 0.34503148 0.32709875 0.91110675
[23] 0.47955652 0.66416799 0.17576377 0.29642451 0.03093203 0.55558049 0.25929024 0.22682266 0.13330299 0.24864748 0.26326284
[34] 0.17119738 0.03866042 0.16836126 0.07008371 0.06618732
```

Have a look over the data (some of it). Of course each patient has a label, wheather he responded or not. what might be a better test for such data? it's not normaly distributed so a t-test won't work.

```
structure(c(3.38095737483041e-19, 0.0754726362795934, 0.027557397055234, 
0.0363740301678021, 4.15340860889611e-18, 0.02169029051764, 2.49939577639468e-19, 
0.152433315256768, 0.00739016812888315, 0.00981199308655118, 
0.128555853055445, 0.0123075842811006, 0.0494228322191279, 0, 
0.00848459593316839, 0, 0.0312597789893442, 0.116541402028993, 
0, 6.12575904517024e-18, 0, 0, 0, 0.00591907451808449, 1.35972128577064e-18, 
0, 0.00752239715395736, 0.00452189827267316, 0.00810259602511851, 
1.90170487163549e-18, 0.00150911618431696, 1.20991079562134, 
0.148090526382757, 0.21240357453739, 0.185732880346548, 0.103184992796001, 
0.0414371463848391, 0.247002038797336, 0.00969832275342574, 0.227939117378352, 
0.401538107546098, 0.286242491355964, 0.0436044350784847, 0.0185009381694827, 
0.0373536569361252, 0.0056354043499611, 0.147235313540746, 0.794836284288179, 
3.19698915577727e-19, 5.96987611714042e-18, 2.14257124512517e-18, 
1.12656229762368e-18, 0.140718919159243, 8.67361737988404e-19, 
0, 0.138246146491289, 0.00168073954319109, 0.108739126261556, 
0.0354775821808617, 0.0318472231689331, 0.00351519831986292, 
0.0299504687720483, 0.0482698978925521, 0.00474311169107073, 
0, 0, 0, 0.110866579707374, 0.011032787151386, 0.00947703999006027, 
0.0387105405512354, 1.34730581356489e-19, 0.00869981105770921, 
0.0488583665807479, 0.0036509413993116, 0.0330957714371347, 0.0322944330634147, 
0.50741768305413, 0, 1.32074152606332e-17, 2.52559437001339e-18, 
0, 0, 0.000183139708058338, 0, 0, 0, 0.0460363010188203, 0.0136409171720756, 
0, 0, 0.00936576956923318, 0.0387601417752215, 1.51197131299736e-20, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00930263164210266, 0, 2.02212305735479e-19, 0.0108668114070633, 
0, 0.00982904416616099, 1.57741210661489e-19, 0.00295616220399211, 
0.594483031575022, 0.0440991346275527, 0.0526648178306062, 0.0170090390580824, 
0.0028167538070276, 1.47822879598295e-19, 0.157968817442628, 
0, 0.0653297540826659, 0.176209625049592, 0.108429451015817, 
0.0307156368784613, 0.0178902521987228, 0.0820342451659127, 3.25021901789351e-20, 
0.0479739709330601, 0.0733801342184468, 0.00843344856376629, 
0, 0.00691308779360455, 1.13305616352041e-18, 0.103781805996856, 
0.00525982662661412, 4.10837721713597e-21, 0.094793976518061, 
0.0169297392022341, 0.0129498366266903, 0.0360692687198391, 0, 
0.146580114766932, 0.194059443833671, 0.0350241892218355, 0.0436456124997203, 
9.94937339877974e-19, 1.50173397625861e-19, 0, 0.152533427494971, 
0.00251919101855609, 0.00192805491625387, 0.101119859282885, 
0.0830425117690383, 0.0279937004765348, 0.0659292488871391, 0.0325187650378906, 
0.00096768334567115, 0.0217183151336949, 0.066885896549415, 5.89038079777836e-20, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0451990989565287, 0.0162470963851934, 0.00584122655553241, 
0.00791668484544163, 0.024334258331078, 0.00646843411720392, 
0, 0, 0.0111489986526388, 0.0210266685705402, 0.138558025748175, 
0.0142310369348761, 0, 6.16272840370192e-18, 0, 0.0136400004130921, 
0.0152665744298628, 0, 0, 0.0255673845760435, 0.00657100746116665, 
0.00670171721583979, 0.026298336167439, 0.00125516305366369, 
0.0707934293276664, 0.107033675626234, 0.000518676278738996, 
1.19583097038147e-18, 2.35228750886349e-19, 4.60543677978312e-19, 
0, 0.0254185585494714, 0.0090719833980293, 0.0327727099107343, 
0.023363807435612, 0.00877588632742558, 0.00346429684382675, 
0, 0.0027444866000587, 0.0501089387551712, 0.0646415634583503, 
0, 1.68390296383475e-18, 1.48385218201839e-19, 0, 0.0310900158922093, 
0.01348865923687, 0, 0.000505810989067718, 0.00161034974515781, 
0.0247341496180466, 0.0214342154596441, 0.00231707664258555, 
2.62862909442698e-20, 0.00516851129967558, 0.0147999388881981, 
0, 0, 3.28594011404599e-21, 2.45045052217226e-18, 0.0246230204227312, 
0.017577360466544, 0, 1.89938262312449e-18, 1.78055540325931e-18, 
0.00389180853714169, 0.024979451298061, 0), dim = c(15L, 15L), dimnames = list(
    c("Adipocytes", "B-cells", "Basophils", "CD4+ memory T-cells", 
    "CD4+ naive T-cells", "CD4+ T-cells", "CD4+ Tcm", "CD4+ Tem", 
    "CD8+ naive T-cells", "CD8+ T-cells", "CD8+ Tcm", "Class-switched memory B-cells", 
    "DC", "Endothelial cells", "Eosinophils"), c("Pt1", "Pt10", 
    "Pt101", "Pt103", "Pt106", "Pt11", "Pt17", "Pt18", "Pt2", 
    "Pt24", "Pt26", "Pt27", "Pt28", "Pt29", "Pt3")))
```

Comment: a) The Wilcoxon rank-sum test (equivalent to the Mann-Whitney test) does not assume paired values.  b) I didn't look at your sample data, but the fact that you are running 38 two-sample tests suggests that you might want to use a single, more complex model.  c) The warnings mean exactly what they say:  This function doesn't compute an ***exact*** *p*-value when there are tied values.  It computes an asymptotic *p*-value.  This is nothing to worry about.  d)  You may want to consider what hypotheses you actually want to test.  A *t*-test is conducted on the means.  (cont...)

Comment: (cont) ...  Whereas the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test looks at the stochastic equivalence of the samples.  (If one sample tends to have higher values than the the other).  First, decide what you want to know.  Likely, the samples having a normal distribution or not will not impede you testing the hypothesis you want to test, even if you need to use alternative tests like permutation tests, and so on.

Comment: What are the units of the values in the data? Are they absolute cell numbers for each cell type, or fractions of cells in each class, or something else? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted. As @SalMangiafico said, there's no problem in principle applying `wilcox.test()` (although a more complete model be better), but I wonder if there's some additional source of variability among individuals that you're not correcting for and thus makes possibly true differences between groups harder to demonstrate.